# Problema de DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, servicio

mi consulta es la siguiente  he realizado un servicio windows
donde en  mi  local funciona correctamente pero  al  ejecutarlo en el servidor me sale el siguiente error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, evita poner imágenes. Ver esto desde el móvil o para personas con alguna limitación, es poco menos que imposible. Ese error se puede poner como texto. Gracias! :)

Comment: que es lo que hace el servicio? usa algun componente de office o sea general algun excel o similar

Comment: Si estás usando recursos del server como directorios necesitas dar el permiso al usuario del servicio en las carpetas correspondientes. En la ventana de servicios si haces click derecho y propiedades en el servicio que cargaste podrás ver el usuario y password o cuenta con que se ejecuta, y podrás cambiarla.